# Reject or Cancel workflow when the item is edited

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, approval-process

I have created a designer workflow on a list. The workflow has an approval process.

I want the workflow to stop when some edit the original item if the approval process is running.

I see a "CancelOnChange" condition, in "When item is changed" step of "Change the behavior of overall task process", but this does not seems to be working.

Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is solved.
CancelOnChange worked. All we need to do is to set the variable to yes before the Start approval step.

Another problem was, i was modifying the status column before the "start approval" step and workflow consider it as a change and reject the workflow. Though i feel it should not be like this.

Ideally it should consider the changes only after the Start Approval process. But for now i have settled with it.